# how to resize an arrow(div) in jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I want to know how to resize an arrow in jquery ui.

the fiddle link is

http://jsfiddle.net/Tr2Fh/

The below is the code:

```
HTML
<div class="connector_box"> </div>

CSS
.connector_box {
margin: 15px auto 10px;
height: 7px;
background: #0076BD;
width: 60px;
}
 .connector_box:after {
  content: "";
   border-top: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   border-bottom: 10px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
   border-left: 10px solid #0076BD;
   float: right;
   margin-top: -7px;
   margin-right: -5px;
  } 

 Jquery
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $( ".connector_box" ).resizable();
 })

 Script Tags
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

I know that it is possible to resize arrow using an image. But the requirement has arised that I have to do it using only divs or spans.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can I ask why you're including `jQuery` 2 times?

Comment: i am using jquery ui which has dependency on jquery

Comment: Oh, nevermind, ignore me.

Comment: the updated fiddleis http://jsfiddle.net/Tr2Fh/2/